# How to bind Build>Project to a key in Javatar (Sublime Text 3)?

Tags: java, sublimetext3, key-bindings, sublime-text-plugin

I want to bind `ctrl+shift+b` to Build All Projects in Javatar but there is no documentation on google to do that. Here are my key binding settings/progress so far:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], 
    "command": "javatar_build_?"
}
```

**What goes into the command argument?? Please help. Your help is deeply appreciated.**

Comment: To run the main class after build, the command is "javatar_run_main".

Answer (score 0):

Edit your keymap entry to look like this:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], 
    "command": "javatar_build",
    "args": {
        "build_type": "project"
    }
}
```

and you should* be good to go.

<sup>* I don't program in Java and I don't have any projects laying around to test, so YMMV. Let me know how it works.</sup>